# How to draw border around the chart area in Google Charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I need a border around just the chart area and not the whole chart. I can't find what property to set. This is in the Google Visualization API.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The appropriate option is undocumented.  You need to set the `chartArea.backgroundColor.stroke` and `chartArea.backgroundColor.strokeWidth` options.  The `stroke` option controls the color of the border, and takes any valid HTML color string.  The `strokeWidth` option controls the width of the border, and takes an integer for the width in pixels:

```
chartArea: {
    backgroundColor: {
        stroke: '#4322c0',
        strokeWidth: 3
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks twice in a day, rather in a few minutes! and you overtake my rep ;-)

Comment: Does not seem to be working with the Google pie chart

Comment: What is the syntax for adding the border AND chart area fill? The docs (as of 6/29/18) say I can use EITHER a string for the color, or an object with stroke and/or strokeWidth properties. But how do I get a fill color and stroke the border? Thanks

Comment: It's been a while since I last used the Visualization API, but I think you can use `chartArea.backgroundColor.fill` to set the background color if you also need to set the stroke.

Comment: That worked (once I managed to type it right). In an options list it will look like this: chartArea: {backgroundColor:{fill:'Ivory', stroke:'black',strokeWidth:2}}